# Pass JavaScript Datetime zone to MVC controller without ActionResult View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need one mvc controller without any View or Actions.
I need to use local browser zone 
offset into varius of mvc controllers

if other browser - client enter
 to site,need to add his local zone
 and to use in all client only inctance

Do you thing that this way is correct regarding this feature?

This is my MVC controller. The first action not have any View and only set browser zone offset. The request call is from JS code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class NoneViewController : Controller
    {
 //POST/NoneViewController/BrowserZoneOffset/-60
        [HttpPost]
        public void BrowserZoneOffset(int zone)
        {

              Requests.Headers.Add("time-zone-offset, zone);
        }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetDateView()
     { 

        // Here need to get inctance only data //from requests. If second browser open
// site need to get his zone
        int mydateOffset = Request.Headers["tume-zone"].FirstOrDefault();

        return new View(...);
     }

 }
```

}

Here is my js where add local browser zone
This js call at the begging of web page home page

```
 @section Scripts { < script type = "text/javascript" >
      //modify as needed to make it pass in what you need.
      function ZoneOffset(zoneId) {
       $.ajax({
         url: "/NoneViewController/BrowserZoneOffset/"+zoneId,
         // data: {zoneId: zoneId },
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         type: "POST",
         success: function(data) {
          //TODO: Add whatever if you want to pass a notification back
         },
         error: function(error) {
          //TODO: Add some code here for error handling or notifications
         }
        } 

// here set local browser zone offest
var dt = Datetime.Now(); var zoneOffset = dt.GetLocalZone();
ZoneOffset(zoneOffset);

< /script>
        }
```

We can set uniq browser zone with that example

```
var localAspNetInctanceBrowser = Session.SessionID;

// int myLocalzone variable was set by 
// JS.datetime.Now().getZoneOffset();

Session[localAspNetInctanceBrowser] = myLocalzone;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `return Json(model)` Then parse the result in your JavaScript code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BrowserZoneOffset(int tz)
{
    PersistentStoreTimeZone(tz);

    return Json(new { status = "success" });
}
```

Though, I don't think any of this is necessary if your datetime string format include the timezone offset.

Comment: Why do we need to return any data in post?

Comment: To verify a successful operation